# How can I define !! as a custom postfix operator?

Tags: swift, operators

I'm trying to create my own custom operator !!

```
postfix operator !! //error

static postfix func !! (optionalValue: Optional<T>) -> T {
        // realisation
    }
```

I get error message

> Expected operator name in operator declaration

in the declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a restricted set of characters can be used for custom operators, and some operators are reserved and cannot be overloaded.
The precise rules are documented in [Lexical Structure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html). In particular (emphasis added):

> Although you can define custom operators that contain a question mark (?), they can’t consist of a single question mark character only. Additionally, although operators can contain an exclamation mark (!), **postfix operators can’t begin with** either a question mark or **an exclamation mark.**

Also

- your operator is *generic,* so you have to declare `T` as the placeholder type  with `<T>`,
- the function must not be `static` unless defined inside a type.

Working example:

```
postfix operator =!!

postfix func =!! <T> (optionalValue: Optional<T>) -> T {
    // realization
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example

```
//Define a operator
prefix operator √

//create a function  and perform the operation.
prefix func √(lhs: Double) -> Double {
return sqrt(lhs)
}

//Do operation 
let someVal:Double = 25
let squareRoot = √someVal // result is 5
```

Comment: This does not compile. The correct version is here:  https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/how-to-create-a-custom-operator-like-operator-in-swift-55953c0c0bf2.

Comment: Don't forget to add a link to the original source when posting code found somewhere else. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.